# Angular 4: what file picker to use to get fullpath name to the selected file?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have to implement/use a file picker in my angular4 application. 
I currently use:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    Import
    <input type="file"
    (change)="import($event)" hidden>
</label>
```

and my handler is as follows:

```
public import($event): void {
    let files = $event.target.files;
    this.scenarioConfig.import(files);
}
```

what I get is that a FileList and each entry only has the filename and does not contain fullpath.
Any way to use a file picker that gives me fullpath to the selected file?

Comment: What do you need the full path for? I'm pretty sure you can't get it for privacy reasons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201258/1849366